# INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY:Android Open Accessory

Tags: android

I know that this question has been posted many times but I am unable to get a clear answer anywhere. So I started a separate post. So the problem `INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY` and the logcat shows the shared library `com.android.future.usb.accessory.jar` is missing. 
I downloaded this jar file separately and then did an adb push to the location system/framework and that location looks something like this

```
 ls system/framework      
ls system/framework   
sqlite-jdbc.jar   
com.android.future.usb.accessory.jar      
ext.jar     
pm.jar    
com.google.android.maps.jar   
services.jar  
core.jar  
svc.jar  
am.jar   
bouncycastle.jar   
android.test.runner.jar   
framework-res.apk   
ime.jar   
input.jar   
core-junit.jar   
android.policy.jar   
framework.jar   
monkey.jar   
com.android.location.provider.jar   
bmgr.jar   
javax.obex.jar    
#
```

but still I am getting the same error!!
My android version is 2.3.4 and I am trying to install the `DemoKit.apk` which is available in the developers website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have it running on an HTC G1, the changes listed in [this github thread](https://github.com/ezterry/manifest-gingerbread-DS/issues/32):

You must register the library at:
/etc/permissions

through XML:
android.hardware.usb.accessory.xml (see official source code)

[A video demonstration](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXOrH24mHNM).